# After showing / hiding divs images appear next to original instead of replacing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created some jquery that shows and then hides various divs based on the users selection in a drop down. I recently posted about this and was very kindly helped, however one of the drop down works as expected and the picture is replaced, the other two the image appears next to the original instead of replacing it, as you can see in the image below.

[image]

Here is the CSS, HTML and jQuery i am using, thank you!

CSS

```
.builder-page .form-container .recipe-settings {
    padding: 40px 10px;
}
.builder-page .form-container .recipe-settings div {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;;
}
.builder-page .form-container .recipe-settings div .box {

    margin: 0px auto;

}
.builder-page .form-container .recipe-settings div .Prepbox {

    margin: 0px auto;

}
.builder-page .form-container .recipe-settings div .Cookbox {

    margin: 0px auto;
}
.builder-page .form-container .recipe-settings div select {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    margin-top: 17px;
    margin-right:100px;
}
.builder-page .form-container .recipe-settings div label {
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="recipe-settings pure-u-1 clearfix">
                                    <div class="pure-u-1-3">
                                        <span class="heading">Portion number</span>
                                      <div id ="option1" class="box"> <img src="assets/images/icon-portions.png" alt="" /> </div>
                                      <div id="option2" class="box"><img src="assets/images/portionFour.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                                      <div id="option3" class="box"><img src="assets/images/portionEight.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                                      <div id="option4" class="box"><img src="assets/images/portionSixteen.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                                        <select id="select-portion" name="portion_num">
                                            <option value="option1">Two</option>
                                            <option value="option2">Four</option>
                                            <option value="option3">Eight</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pure-u-1-3">
                                        <span class="heading">Preparation time</span>
                                        <div id ="option10" class="Prepbox"> <img src="assets/images/icon-clock.png" alt="" /> </div>
                                        <div id="option11" class="PrepBox"> <img src="assets/images/SixtyMins.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                                        <div id="option12" class="PrepBox"> <img src="assets/images/Ninty.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                                        <div id="option13" class="PrepBox"> <img src="assets/images/OneFifty.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                                        <select id="select-prep-time" name="prep_time">
                                            <option value="option10">Two</option>
                                            <option value="option11">Four</option>
                                            <option value="option12">Eight</option>
                                        </select>
                                        <label for="increase-preparation-time"><input type="checkbox" id="increase-preparation-time" name="prepAddTime" /> Increase according to portion number</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="addedPrepTime" name="addedPrepTime" value="" placeholder="Added Prep Time Per Person"  class="element pure-u-10" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pure-u-1-3">
                                        <span class="heading">Cooking time</span>
                                       <div id ="cook1" class="Cookbox">  <img src="assets/images/icon-clock.png" alt="" /> </div>
                                       <div id="cook2" class="CookBox"> <img src="assets/images/SixtyMins.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                                       <div id="cook3" class="CookBox"> <img src="assets/images/Ninty.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                                        <select id="select-cook-time" name="cook_time">
                                            <option value="cook1">Two</option>
                                            <option value="cook2">Four</option>
                                            <option value="cook3">Eight</option>
                                        </select>
                                        <label for="increase-cooking-time"><input type="checkbox" id="increase-cooking-time" name="cookAddTime" /> Increase according to portion number</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="addedCookTime" name="addedCookTime" value="" placeholder="Extra cook time per extra person"  class="element pure-u-10" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

jQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.box').hide();
    $('#option1').show();
    $('#select-portion').change(function () {
        $('.box').hide();
        $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
    });

});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.PrepBox').hide();
    $('#option10').show();
    $('#select-prep-time').change(function () {
        $('.PrepBox').hide();
        $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
    });

});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.CookBox').hide();
    $('#cook1').show();
    $('#select-cook-time').change(function () {
        $('.CookBox').hide();
        $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have two different classes declared (I showed this in my answer on your other thread) the first one never gets hidden when the function is called -

```
<div id ="option10" class="Prepbox"> <img src="assets/images/icon-clock.png" alt="" /> </div>
<div id="option11" class="PrepBox"> <img src="assets/images/SixtyMins.jpg" alt="" /></div>
```

Change the first one to `class="PrepBox"` and your issue should clean itself up.

Comment: Not sure how i didn't see that! Thank you very much

Comment: (Sorry for the repost) :)

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you have these `div` elements that have a class different from everyone else's:

```
<div id ="option10" class="Prepbox"> <img src="assets/images/icon-clock.png" alt="" /> </div>
```

and

```
<div id ="cook1" class="Cookbox">  <img src="assets/images/icon-clock.png" alt="" /> </div>
```

Whenever you would tell `.PrepBox` or `.CookBox` to `hide()` or `show()`, the elements above (respectively) would not be affected.